# No Cold Water in Shower ever

Tags: water, shower

So a few years back I installed a new bathroom for my kids, and lately, my eldest has been waking up earlier; she wants to take cold showers. I never really thought about cold showers, and when she said that she doesn't know how to turn on the cold water. I remember back, and we never have had cold water in that shower. 
How do we get cold water installed?

Comment: Just for clarification.  You are stating that only a hot water line was hooked up to this shower?  It would seem to be very unsafe unless your hot water tank temperature is set to the lowest setting.  In most home the hot water is set to 125-130 degrees which is still pretty hot.

Comment: Are you sure you don’t have a preset faucet? I have used these when my kids were younger to prevent scalding , my brother used similar to save on the electric bill. Check and see if your faucet is set . And if the temp span can be adjusted.

Comment: Post a picture of the faucet and, if possible the plumbing on the back side. There should be an access panel of some sort to allow you (or your plumber) to get to the pipes without tearing up the wall.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the valve, mostly, barring a very unlikely arrangement of no cold supply (perhaps fed by a tempering valve if nobody's been scalded, but really, no cold supply is unlikely, while a poor user interface on the valve is very likely, at least in USA plumbing)

i.e. one common USA style of shower valve has essentially no "amount" of water control, and starts "cold" where it's near the off position, on up to hot furthest away from the on position. So if you think you are turning it "fully on" you are really just turning it fully hot. So, cold is "just barely turned on" for that style of valve.

But, I have experienced a surprising number of that sort of shower control that appears to be plumbed exactly backwards to the labels, so it starts full hot near the off position, and goes to full cold. I do not trust the labeling on any new one I meet. I'm not really fond of those anyway, but they are common.

There are various other options, depending what you have for a shower control valve.

Comment: This type is _very_ common in hotels. You get no control whatsoever over pressure, just temperature. They're often labeled incorrectly, and I've see some installed upside down. I agree 100% with the "don't trust" and the "not fond"!